# GetElement methods not working in Gmail

Tags: javascript

For some reason, getElementById() and getElementsByClassName() cannot locate many of the elements on gmail.
For example, the div entitled "Mail" on the navigation bar has the code:

```
<div id=":qy" class="z9 z8 T2"><span class="is">Mail</span><div class="Ww4Jzd"></div></div>
```

Yet running `document.getElementById(":qy")` in the Chrome console doesn't find it. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure they're not in iframes or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in iframes. This should do it:

```
document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById(':qy')
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs may not start with a colon.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Pratik Well, that *was* two years ago, and it is a valid reason the `getElementById` may have not work.

Comment: I didn't realize this thing in short description that's why I have comment it